# SQL - referencing a column name with [ , ] characters

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that contains the column name `distance[m]` - what is the right way to reference this in a SQL query like below

```
SELECT
  AVG(distance[m]) AS avg_distance
FROM
  distance_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using double quote characters (`"`) - like so:

```
SELECT
  AVG("distance[m]") AS avg_distance
FROM
  distance_table
```